# Android Studio does not zipalign signed APKs

Tags: android, android-studio

I use Android Studio to create Android Apps. When I created signed apps, using the option "Build -> Generate Signed APK..." in Android Studio I selec the previously created keystore file and start the generation process. Everything seems to work fine.

Then I try to updload the app into the Play Developer Console, and get the error, that the app is not zipaligned.

Now I zipalign the app by hand, using the command line. Now uploading the app works.

Cant I zipalign the app in the APK generation process right away using Android Studio?

Comment: same here... In the last 4 years I never had this issue -.- password is correct. weird. do you use a mac?